# JQuery jquery-1.7.1.min.js live() deprecated use on()

Tags: jquery, live

from jQuery website:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers.

with version 1.7.1 i tried to change all my live() to on(), but none worked. Does anyone has any idea why?

---

this is how it gets called:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

and this is one of the scripts that don't work:

```
$(".toBeSaved [col=ISRC] input").on('change',function() {
        var pid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('primary_key');
        $("[primary_key="+pid+"] [col=isrc_id] input").val('');
        $("[primary_key="+pid+"] [col=isrc_id] input").css({'border':'1px solid red','background-color':'#e8b7cf'});
    });
```

html:

```
<tr primary_key="44" class="toBeSaved">
<td col="ISRC" style="width: 91px; " class="editableCell"><input class="editableInput auto" type="text" undefined=""></td>
<td col="LineYear" style="width: 35px; " class="editableCell"><input class="editableInput  " type="text"></td>
<td col="isrc_id" style="width: 41px; " class="editableCell"><input class="editableInput undefined" type="text" undefined="" readonly="readonly"></td></tr>
```

and can i just ask - why "-1"?? what **exactly** is wrong with my question?

Comment: could you please post your code ? did you really include the newest version ? is it being loaded ? how do you call it ?

Comment: Show us an example of what didn't work, and check the console for errors.

Comment: You can't just replace the `.live` calls with `.on` calls, they accept slightly different arguments.

Comment: i have edited my post with some code

Answer (score 7):

Converting code from using `.live` to `.on` isn't just a case of replacing the calls to `.live` with `.on` calls. They accept different arguments, and are called on different selectors. For example, the old syntax:

```
$('a').live('click', function () {});
```

With `.on`:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {});
```

This syntax gives you greater control and flexibility.

I would recommend reading the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

And for information on converting to `.on` from `.live`:
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I couldn't: the OP has asked a fairly generic question (how do I convert some old code to some new code), and hadn't provided any code to make an example of. I understand your point though. Should I have waited for the OP to provide a code sample?

Comment: Yes, if you're just going to link to some API docs then it's best to leave those as a comment.

Comment: i have read the manual of course. an i believe my code is correct to what's specified. no need posting links to manuals. i can find them myself - especially, since, as i copied quote form the manual.

Comment: You clearly *haven't* read the documentation, it has a very clear section on converting to .on which very clearly says that you call it on the document object. I'm adding a code example to my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to the code submitted, as per the ramblings above;

Replace

```
$(".toBeSaved [col=ISRC] input").on('change',function() {
```

with

```
 $(document).on('change','.toBeSaved [col=ISRC] input', function() {
```